# Image rating where average rating is published in Drupal RSS feed

Tags: drupal, photo-gallery

Totally new to Drupal so be gentle please!

Let's say I have a number of user uploaded images and I want them to vote [1 to 5 stars] on the images that are presented.

Does anyone know the right combination of modules and settings to get Drupal publishing the average rating of content in an rss feed?

I've looked at the Voting API and FiveStar modules but I don't see any options for publishing rating information in the feed.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

PS. Drupal is not my only option at this point since it's very early, but I haven't found any other open source solutions that do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Views and ViewsRSS combined with the Voting modules, and add a Filter that filters out nodes that are above a certain rating.

http://drupal.org/project/views

http://drupal.org/project/views_rss

As for the core RSS Drupal, I don't think you can set it parameters like you can with Views.